# A way of sending e-mail on SQL Server after trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

What is the best way of sending e-mail on SQL Server with an `after` trigger? I have found some articles on that but they seem to be a little old.

My goal here is to send an e-mail to admin that some values are inserted into a table.

I am on SQL Server 2008 R2 now.

Comment: Database Mail?  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend inserting a record into an emailPending table in the trigger, then have a job that inspects this table and sends any emails.

Putting a send_dbmail inside a trigger is not advisable because send_dbmail can stall for any number of reasons.

Comment: +1, this is how we do it.  I do seem to remember a few second wait for each call to sp_send_dbmail, so the `emailPending` table and processing job is the "trick" the OP is after.  slow triggers are a killer, and if you have lots of transactions they can lead to locking, blocking and deadlocks.  it is best to have your triggers run very fast, without looping and any dependency on a procedure like sp_send_dbmail.

Comment: I agree with Jimbo, I implemented send_dbmail on our server and kaboom, all transaction was locked. So better not use trigger.

Answer (score 1):

just execute [EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) from inside the trigger, or am I missing something here?

aditional reading: [Database Mail and SQL Mail Stored Procedures (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177580.aspx) and [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx)

Comment: I am not so much familiar with triggers so I am looking for some tricks if they exist on this situation.